# How to run multiple VBA procedures on multiple sheets at once, except for one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run the same set of procedures on all worksheets at once except for the a sheet titled "summary". This is what I've tried, and I keep getting different types of errors. The procedure I'm calling is a procedure that calls other procedures, maybe that is the issue?

```
Option Explicit
Sub runAll()
  
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "summary" Then
       
     Call Formatting

    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Contained in the Formatting sub are more calls.

```
Sub oracleCogsUniversal()
Call Formatting
Call DeleteDetails
Call addSummary
Call pasteID
Call moveUp
Call formatFile
End Sub
```

Comment: The sub function call should not be the issue. What are the "different" types of issues? First step would be to remark out the CALL Formatting function, and do a debug.print ws.name to make sure your loop logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to debug this. First thing I would do is this:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub runAll()        
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          Debug.print ws.name  
       Next ws 
    End Sub
```

to make sure your sheet names are as you expect. Open the Immediate Window and see what is output. Chances are the name is not "summary" as you expect. If it is not, change your <> "summary" statement to the correct name. Once that is worked out, in your "Formatting" function, remark everything out and reenable each line, or section, one at a time until you find the error.

The only way to get to the bottom of this is to debug it systematically.

Answer (score 0):

In `runAll` you only call `Formatting` - did you mean to call `oracleCogsUniversal`? You don't pass anything to those sub-procedures, so I'm guessing there's no way for them to know which sheet they're supposed to be operating on?

You should be passing `ws` to `oracleCogsUniversal`, and that in turn should maybe be passing that worksheet reference on to anything else it calls, so the called code can work on a specific worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub runAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "summary" Then
           oracleCogsUniversal ws     '<< pass along the `ws` reference; use of Call is deprecated
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub oracleCogsUniversal(ws As Worksheet) '<< get `ws` from `runAll`
    Formatting ws                        '<< pass ws to called Sub
    DeleteDetails ws
    addSummary ws
    pasteID ws
    moveUp ws
    formatFile ws
End Sub


Sub Formatting(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True 'work directly on `ws`
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, yes my mistake. oracleCogsUniversal is what I meant to call in runAll. Can you clarify what is happening in the last sub Formatting?  would i do that for each procedure? Then at the end would i run a procedure that calls runAll, oracleCogsUniversal, and Formatting? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Formatting` was just an example to show how you'd use the `ws` reference passed along from `runAll` via `oracleCogsUniversal`, to work with a specific worksheet.   I can't see what's in those methods called from `oracleCogsUniversal`, so I can't be more specific than that.  You would do something similar for the other methods, Yes.